# CSS - Horizontally and vertically distribute divs

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-align

So I've got this header with three elements in them.
What I want is basically this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zktbfmqo/2/

Only with vertically centered content in each of the divs as well.
Is there an easy and clever way to do this without using absolutes etc?
Vertical-align: middle doesn't seem to do much, but that property isn't always easy to work with either.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box1">Text</div>
    <div class="box2">Text</div>
    <div class="box3">Text</div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    height: 125px;

    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;

    min-width: 612px;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 125px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can achieve the same result in a better way by using Flexbox.

For vertical align text to the middle you can simply approach that by adding the line-height property and set it to the same exact height of the container div so in your case it would be 125px or if you used flexbox it can be done with align-items: center , and here is the final code:

```css
.wrapper {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;

-webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
flex-flow: row nowrap;

-webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* Safari 6.1+ */
justify-content: space-between;
  
font-weight: bold;

height: 125px;
min-width: 612px;
padding: 5px;

border: 2px dashed #444;
}

.wrapper > div{
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-basis: 150px;
flex-basis: 150px;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

}
.aside-1, .aside-3{
background: #ccc
}
.aside-2{
background: #0ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="aside aside-1">text1</div>
   <div class="aside aside-2">text2</div>
   <div class="aside aside-3">text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I went for this, and tried a polyfill for flexbox for IE9 etc. Haven't tested it yet though, but flexbox is wonderful :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display:table/table-cell` and using a workaround with `border-collapse/spacing` + `margin` you will get the desired output.

```css
#wrap {
  border: 2px dashed #444;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
  overflow:hidden;
  /* just for demo */
  width: 612px;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 -81px; /*must be equal to border-spacing */
  
}
#table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 81px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
.stretch {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
.box1,
.box3 {
  background: #ccc
}
.box2,
.box4 {
  background: #0ff
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="table">
      <div class="box1">Text</div>
      <div class="box2">Text</div>
      <div class="box3">Text</div>
      <span class="stretch"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox to the rescue!

Good resources:

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/

https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

```css
#container {
    display: flex; /* magic maker */
    justify-content: space-between; /* set equal space between boxes */
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    height: 125px;
    
    /* just for demo */
    min-width: 612px;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4 {
    display: flex; /* magic maker */
    /*  
        shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis properties
        we don't want the boxes to grow or shrink, and the basis is the explicit
        width we want them
    */
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    justify-content: center; /* horizontally center text within */
    align-items: center; /* vertically center text within */
    height: 125px;
}

.box1, .box3 {
    background: #ccc
}
.box2, .box4 {
    background: #0ff
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box1">Text</div>
    <div class="box2">Text</div>
    <div class="box3">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Reading OP's code I think OP wants to give support to old browsers so flexbox probably won't be a good solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with Bootstrap?

It is a CSS Framework made by Twitter.

Put this inside of your head -

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>
```

Use this in your body to see what it does, there's great docs on it.

```
<div class="container"> <!-- Creates margin -->
  <div class="row"> <!-- Read docs on rows, they're awesome! -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">   <!-- 1 -->
      <!-- Just to take up space -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">   <!-- 2 -->
      <!-- YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">  <!-- 3 -->
    <!-- Just to take up space -->
    </div>
  </div> <!-- ./row -->
</div> <!-- ./container -->
```

Now inside of the 2nd ./col-lg-4 div all of that content will be perfectly centered in the screen with the text aligned left.

If you want to align center the text, replace

```
<div class="col-lg-4"> <!-- 2 -->
```

with

```
<div class="col-lg-4 text-center"> <!-- 2 -->
```

Hope this helps!